# Reading strings from console and storing in array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

The input will be read through console. Example: code.exe < sample.txt

The sample.txt looks something like this:

```
1 + 2
3 + 4
6 + 9
```

I'm trying to create a program that reads the input through the console, then stores the data into an array. This is the code I created, and I can't figure out why there's an error.

```
int main(void) {
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int line[1000][1000];

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        line[i][j] = c;
        j++;
        if(c == '\n') {
            line[i][j] = 0;
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
```

This code tries to do the following:

line[0][0] <- {1, +, 2}

line[1][0] <- {3, +, 4}

line[2][0] <- {6, +, 9}

Thank you so much! :)

Edit: The error I get is basically,  "code.exe has stopped working" Sorry that's not very informative :/

Comment: You never initialize `i`, its value will be *indeterminate*.

Comment: And Need reset `j` each newline.

Comment: And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question to give us more details about the "error" you have.

Comment: you are using line[][] and defined lines[][]...

Comment: line to lines was a typo when I posted here :) but thank you to everyone for the advice. Will revise code.

Answer (score 0):

OP here.

I got the code running. Apparently my mistake was making an array of size [1000][1000]. I realized that that's about 1,000,000 * 4 bytes ~ 4 MB of contiguous memory. The code works when the size of the array is smaller.

Here's my code now.

```
int main(void) {
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int line[100][100];

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        line[i][j] = c;
        j++;
        if(c == '\n') {
            line[i][j] = 0;
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}
```